# How long of no salt diet before sodium levels return to normal and water retention stops decreasing?

Tags: salt

```
Adult male, 47, 77 kilos, 169 cm
```

I lost about 2 kilos in about 15 days from a daily 1500 calories healthy diet of fruits, veggies, lean meats, lots of water and no processed foods. I run 10 km a day and swim 20 minutes on off days.

That sounds too fast to be true...

So I suspect I had water retention, I used to eat tons of salt, like over 6000 mg a day.

Now I have cut down to absolutely no salt added.

Are the 2 kilos attributed to water retention?

Would it be ok for me to go back on a 500mg to 1500mg daily sodium intake or will the water retention come back?

Long question, but confused why I lost so much weight so fast!

Comment: 1 kg of body fat is about 8000 Kcal and someone of your weight running for an hour will burn something of the order of 1000 Kcal. A basal metabolic rate of 1500 Kcal is quite realistic for someone your length, so an energy deficit of 1000 Kcal is possible. This would have led to 2 kg weight loss in 16 days, which is pretty much what you've measured.

Comment: So not attributed to salt?

Comment: I don't think so (at least not that most of the 2 kg is lost fluids), but you can just monitor your weight loss during the next two weeks and see you continue to lose weight at this rate. If you keep on exercising at the current intensity and frequency and you keep on eating 1500 Kcal you should continue to lose weight at pretty much this rate until you near certain limits for recuperation. Recuperation from exercise also requires energy, as you lose fat reserves the energy per unit time that can be extracted from fat will fall short, you may then start to feel tired and hungry.

Comment: I don't think 2 kilos in 15 days is a surprising amount of weight loss given your calorie restriction and exercise level. Sure, reducing your sodium intake almost certainly caused some water loss, but how much was water, how much was fat, and how much was muscle is a difficult question and you haven't provided the data that would allow a reasonable estimate.

Comment: I have always exercised, so only 2 things changed. Salt from 6000 mg a day to 1000 mg, and calories from 2500 to 1500